# How to start Spyder in macOS?

Tags: macos, installation, spyder

I've installed python3.6 as below but unsure how to access Spyder.  Most of what I have read is unclear, i.e. saying if should already have Spyder? I have completed my set-up using Learn Python the Hard Way on a Macbook Pro.

Install instruction: Gotohttps://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-360/anddownloadthe”macOS64-bit/32- bit installer”. Install it like you would any other software.

Terminal > Python version: 
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 22 2016, 17:23:13) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Any help appreciated.

Steve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Using Spyder is very simple, but not the way you're trying to do it.

Please remove what you've installed so far. Then simply download and install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/). After that, look for an application called *Anaconda Navigator* with Spotlight and finally start Spyder from it.

*Note*: The way you're trying to install Spyder (by using pip on a Python version you downloaded from Python.org) is only recommended to very knowledgeable people because it's really hard to get all Spyder dependencies installed correctly and without problems. That's why we recommend to use Anaconda instead, which is way easier and safer.

Comment: Worked perfect, thanks for a great introduction to stackoverflow.com and your community :)

Comment: Glad to know you're now a happy Spyder user! One last lesson about StackOverflow: please mark my answer as correct by selecting the green check mark to the left. That way other people will know it's right.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Hi, but is seems strange that I have to start anaconda in order to start spyder... I would like to use spyder like RStudio. Is that possible?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible at the moment, sorry.

Comment: I wish there was a stand alone Spyder icon that could launch Spyder like on a windows. Or at least a way to launch Spyder from the terminal like in earlier versions of MacOS (before Catalina). Launching the anaconda navigator is a drag - very slow and clunky